# Why does sscanf need & for %d integers but not for %s strings

Tags: c, scanf

I am confused about the arguments in sscanf routine

```
#include <string.h>
char sentence[20];
char first_name[7];
char last_name[7];
int age;

strcpy(sentence, "aaaaaa bbbbbb 20");
sscanf(sentence, "%s %s %d", first_name, last_name, &age);
```

Why is that char arrays do not need & prefixed but integer variable does?

Thank you

Comment: because array name is a reference to base address

Comment: array decays to pointer, so it already has the address of the string

Comment: with a dynamic allocation, your variable sentence could be wrote like `char *sentence = malloc(sizeof(char) *20);` Maybe it's will help you understand

Answer (score 3):

A string in C is a sequence of characters followed by a '\0' character. The name of an array in C is the address of the initial element. So for a single integer you will need to add the '&' to pass the address where you want to store the int.

Answer (score 0):

In C, the name of the array represents the base address.
In `sscanf()` you need to pass the memory location where variable value could be stored. So `&` means `address of`, is used to get the address in case of primitive types. That is why `&` is used with `int` data type. But string being the array (followed by `'\0'`) of characters, name provides the base address.

Comment: They are all pointers but not to same same type of data : `arr` is a pointer to an array of x elements of a given type, `&arr` is a pointer, to a pointer to an array of x elements of a given type and `&arr[0]` is a pointer to an element of the array elements type.

Answer (score 0):

`&` in the called function implies **address of**.

`sscanf` expects address of variables so that it can store the read values from the given string into those addresses (and hence in those variables).

An array name in C by itself refers to address of first array element, but for a variable, you need to specify the address of the variable.

Answer (score -1):

In C, the identifier of array of character is decayed as a pointer to the first element of the array.

`sscanf()` function needs a pointer to a memory location to write in it, if you pass an `int` type, you should prefix the variable name with `&` which has for effect to pass the address of the variable. This way, sscanf can write directly on the memory location of the variable. You are passing an argument by reference, not by copy.

Since the array name is decayed to a pointer to the first element of the array, you do not need to prefix it with `&` because `sscanf` already access the memory location.

Comment: No, you got the type wrong, array name becomes pointer to *the first element of the array*, not the whole array (it has the same raw value, of course).

Comment: @hyde : You are right, the post is corrected. I confused with `&sentence` which return a pointer to the array, not the first element.